# Free Amazon AWS/RDS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have hosted a server app on AWS and RDS for relational DB. Though I opted for free account, RDS is being charged at $0.0025 per hour amounting to $18 a month.

I read some documentation but still not able to figure this out. Is this the way it is or is there a way to get free RDS account for testing purpose?

Thanks
OpenTube

Comment: There is no such thing as "opting for a free account".  There is a free usage tier which consists of specific resources and limits that will not incur charges, often for limited time periods.  Anything you use over those limits or not in those specifications will incur charges.

Answer (score 7):

I've just started setting this up and I realized quickly that it was allowing me to make selections that couldn't possibly be free.  When setting up your free teir instance, look on the left hand side of the screen for

> Your current selection is eligible for the free tier.

Once you select something like "Multi-AZ Deployment" or use any DB Instance Class other than "db.t2.micro" it will slyly change the left column display:

> The following selections disqualify the instance from being eligible for the free tier:
>
> > Multi-AZ Deployment

Just be careful in your selections and usage to maintain the free teir.

Comment: This is the most accurate answer. all others are outdated.+1

Comment: From that I understand, the free tier is limited to 12 months. After that it’s about $18 per month.

Answer (score 4):

What type of database are you running ? The free tier only applies to SQL Server Micro DB Instance:

> 750 hours of Amazon RDS for SQL Server Micro DB Instance usage
>   (running SQL Server Express Edition in a single Availability Zone)

See http://aws.amazon.com/free/

There is also a 60 day free trial for MySQL and Oracle:

See http://aws.amazon.com/rds/free-trial/

Comment: I use MySQL. Thanks for the link. Will check.

Comment: I simply created a database (connected but hadn't inserted anyhting or run any other queries) to test RDS. Precisely 91 hours later, I went back to check my statement and I'm being charged the following because, when offered, I thought multi-region sounded pretty good for redundancy... :-P

"$0.070 per RDS Micro, Multi-AZ Instance hour (or partial hour)  91 Hrs  $6.37"

Answer (score 2):

Your simplest option is to install the database on your instance.

Alternatively you could look at using a hosted MySQL service provided like http://xeround.com/, or http://www.cleardb.com/, both have limited but free options.

Answer (score 1):

As of October 1st 2012, AWS free usage tier now includes Amazon RDS.
The free tier applies to Single-AZ deployments of MySQL, Oracle “Bring-Your-Own-License (BYOL)” licensing model and SQL Server Express Edition.

See this link from Amazon for more details:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/10/01/amazon-rds-aws-free-tier/

Answer (score 1):

you should use t1.micro. It is at the bottom of the options.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is not to choose RDS Aurora.
If you choose MySql or Postgres, the webpage will show template Free Tier.
When select it, all default configs will be good for free tier.

Some screenshots:
https://www.golery.com/pencil/zr

Answer (score 0):

I recently provisioned an AWS RDS instance. I thought I was within my free tier limit and I kept being charged for "Amazon Relational Database Service Provisioned Storage". It was always a few cents.

[image]

I had taken between 15 and 20 GB of storage when I set it up.

I contacted support and they told me that, in order to be within the RDS free tier, I have to take no more than 9Gb storage when provisioning the instance. But after the backup is made, it will use up an additional 9Gb, so the total storage should be no more than 20Gb.

[image]

So now, when I provisioned a new instance of 9 GB, I am within the limits of the free tier.

[image]

Also always check if in the region of choice they have free tier resources.